# Autocomplete com requisições duplicadas

Tags: angular, typescript, autocompletar

Olá, escrevi um código de autocomplete, porém as requisições ficam duplicadas sempre que pressiono uma nova tecla, a partir da quantidade superior ao que foi estipulado no filter.
Por exemplo, quando digito 4 teclas, faz 4 requisições, quando digito 5 teclas, faz 5 requisições e assim por diante.
Já mudei o evento no HTML para "change", porém o problema persiste.

```
     public autocomplete(){
        this.formTickets
            .get('nomeCliente')
            .valueChanges
            .pipe(filter(v => v.length > 3),
                  debounceTime(500),
                  distinctUntilChanged(),
                  switchMap(termo => this.clienteService.autocomplete(termo)),
            .subscribe(result => {
              
              let sucesso = result.success;
              if(sucesso == true){
                this.clientes = result.data;
              }
              
              console.log(this.clientes);
            });
      }
```

```
<div class="form-group col-md-10">
   <label class="mb-0">Nome Cliente</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="nomeCliente" (change)="autocomplete()" list="dynmicUserIds"/>
   <datalist id="dynmicUserIds">
      <option *ngFor="let item of clientes">{{item.nome}}</option>
   </datalist>
</div>
```

Comment: vc tem que chamar no on init do seu ts inves do change

Comment: Eduardo, era isso mesmo, removi o evento change e coloquei a chamada no onInit e funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado !